# Can we get a "show all" link under the achievements menu?

Tags: feature-request, achievements-dialog

I think a "See all" link would be useful next to the word "Achievements" in the achievements menu. Or after scrolling to the bottom like the inbox menu.

Comment: You can see reputation changes on [your reputation tab](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/202832/mooseman?tab=reputation), badges on [your badges tab](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/202832/mooseman?tab=badges). Do you really need to see this often enough that you need more than that? If so, why? I don't think I've ever wanted to see my reputation changes having occurred longer than a week ago.

Comment: At the moment, the achievements dialog doesn't even show all the rep changes from yesterday. It wouldn't be difficult to make a show all link, even if it just goes to the Activity tab.

Comment: If it doesn't show all rep changes from yesterday, that sounds like a possible bug, most likely not something that will be fixed by a "show all" link. Assuming that's not the only issue, why else do you want this? I don't know about everyone else, but I can't support a feature request if I can't see a legitimate, common use for it - you should always properly justify your feature requests.

Comment: 1) Makes it consistent with the inbox dialog. 2) A more convenient link (and a more obvious link for new users) to show more listings once you've scrolled to the end. 3) The maximum number of listings loaded in the dialog is 50.